# SSL Handshake failure with Java version "1.7.0_79"

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

I am communicating with one of the host in Java using Apache HttpClient and it is throwing `handshake_failure`. The full trace is

> trigger seeding of SecureRandom done seeding SecureRandom Ignoring
>   unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring
>   unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring
>   unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 Ignoring unsupported cipher
>   suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 Ignoring unsupported
>   cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring unavailable
>   cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 Ignoring unavailable cipher
>   suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA Ignoring unsupported cipher
>   suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 Ignoring unsupported
>   cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>   Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   Allow unsafe renegotiation: false Allow legacy hello messages: true Is
>   initial handshake: true Is secure renegotiation: false %% No cached
>   client session
>   *** ClientHello, TLSv1 RandomCookie:  GMT: 1477593324 bytes = { 140, 171, 214, 217, 33, 165, 60, 228, 102, 207, 88, 112, 29, 40, 198, 242,
>   159, 61, 172, 89, 116, 98, 7, 195, 182, 144, 159, 226 } Session ID: 
>   {} Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
>   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
>   SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
>   Compression Methods:  { 0 } Extension elliptic_curves, curve names:
>   {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1,
>   sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1,
>   secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2,
>   sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1,
>   secp256k1} Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
>   Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name:
>   integration.swiggy.com]**
>    [write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 180 0000: 01 00 00 B0 03 01 58 12   49 EC 8C AB D6 D9 21 A5  ......X.I.....!. 0010: 3C E4 66 CF 58 70
>   1D 28   C6 F2 9F 3D AC 59 74 62  <.f.Xp.(...=.Ytb 0020: 07 C3 B6 90 9F
>   E2 00 00   2A C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0  ............./. 0030: 04 C0 0E 00
>   33 00 32 C0   08 C0 12 00 0A C0 03 C0  ....3.2......... 0040: 0D 00 16
>   00 13 C0 07 C0   11 00 05 C0 02 C0 0C 00  ................ 0050: 04 00
>   FF 01 00 00 5D 00   0A 00 34 00 32 00 17 00  ......]...4.2... 0060: 01
>   00 03 00 13 00 15 00   06 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00  ................ 0070:
>   18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00   0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00  ................
>   0080: 11 00 02 00 12 00 04 00   05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00 
>   ................ 0090: 0B 00 02 01 00 00 00 00   1B 00 19 00 00 16 69
>   6E  ..............in 00A0: 74 65 67 72 61 74 69 6F   6E 2E 73 77 69 67
>   67 79  tegration.swiggy 00B0: 2E 63 6F 6D
>   .com main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 180 [Raw write]: length =
>   185 0000: 16 03 01 00 B4 01 00 00   B0 03 01 58 12 49 EC 8C 
>   ...........X.I.. 0010: AB D6 D9 21 A5 3C E4 66   CF 58 70 1D 28 C6 F2
>   9F  ...!.<.f.Xp.(... 0020: 3D AC 59 74 62 07 C3 B6   90 9F E2 00 00 2A
>   C0 09  =.Ytb........*.. 0030: C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E   00 33 00 32 C0
>   08 C0 12  .../.....3.2.... 0040: 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00 16   00 13 C0 07
>   C0 11 00 05  ................ 0050: C0 02 C0 0C 00 04 00 FF   01 00 00
>   5D 00 0A 00 34  ...........]...4 0060: 00 32 00 17 00 01 00 03   00 13
>   00 15 00 06 00 07  .2.............. 0070: 00 09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B   00
>   0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E  ................ 0080: 00 0F 00 10 00 11 00 02
>   00 12 00 04 00 05 00 14  ................ 0090: 00 08 00 16 00 0B 00
>   02   01 00 00 00 00 1B 00 19  ................ 00A0: 00 00 16 69 6E 74
>   65 67   72 61 74 69 6F 6E 2E 73  ...integration.s 00B0: 77 69 67 67 79
>   2E 63 6F   6D                       wiggy.com Exception in thread
>   "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
>   handshake_failure     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
>     at
>   HttpURLConnectionExample.sendGet1(HttpURLConnectionExample.java:83)
>     at HttpURLConnectionExample.main(HttpURLConnectionExample.java:48)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   [Raw read]: length = 5 0000: 15 03 01 00 02
>   ..... [Raw read]: length = 2 0000: 02 28
>   .( main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2 main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal,
>   handshake_failure main, called closeSocket() main, handling exception:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
>   handshake_failure

I have tried many things, but cannot figure out what exactly is the issue.

Comment: Java 7 doesn't automatically support TLS v1.2. See http://superuser.com/questions/747377/enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-for-clients-on-java-7

Comment: What version of SSL/TLS is the other side using? Since Java 7u75, SSLv3 is disabled by default, see: [Oracle info](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/cve-2014-3566-2342133.html)

Comment: Also some more useful info from Oracle: [Diagnosing TLS, SSL, and HTTPS](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https)

Comment: You are right, I added -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1  to my startup parameters, but still the same issue. The other side is https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=integration.swiggy.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that there aren't any common ciphersuites shared by integration.swiggy.com and Java 7. Enabling TLSv1.2 isn't going to help.

You can download the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files for Java 7 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html and replace the two JARs (local_policy.jar, US_export_policy.jar) under your JRE's lib/security directory with the ones from the downloaded package. This will add additional (stronger) ciphersuites and you should be able to connect without having to make any changes to your code or enable TLSv1.2.

For reference, here are the ciphersuites available in Java 7 (1.7.0_79):

```
Default Cipher
        SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
*       SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
*       SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
        SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
        SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
        SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
*       SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
        SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
*       SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
*       SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
*       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
*       TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
        TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
        TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
        TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
        TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
        TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
        TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
        TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
        TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
*       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
```

and here are the ones after using the Unlimited Stringth Jurisdiction policy files:

```
Default Cipher
        SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
*       SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
*       SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
        SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
        SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
        SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
*       SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
        SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
*       SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
*       SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
*       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
*       TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
        TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
        TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
        TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
        TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
        TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
        TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
        TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
        TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
*       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
```

The ciphersuites offered by integration.swiggy.com are:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)   DH 2048 bits   FS  256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)   DH 2048 bits   FS  128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x6b)   DH 2048 bits   FS  256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)   DH 2048 bits   FS 256
```

None of these are in the standard set of ciphersuites provided by Java 7. However, the last 4 get added via the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files.

Comment: Added both JARs in jre/lib/security, but the expected magic didn't happened here. Any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

To add to Anand Bhat's answer, I am showing the diff in client ciphers enabled with the download of Oracle JDK7 Unlimited Strength policy JARs.  However, some servers agree to proceed only with newer ciphers even under TLSv1.2.  In particular, the latest publically available JDK 7 build 80 does not support "GCM cipher suites", resulting in a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`.

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8180834

```diff
$ diff -U 1000000 -u ciphers-jdk7-80-orig.txt ciphers-jdk7-80-unlimited.txt
--- ciphers-jdk7-80-orig.txt    2019-01-17 16:03:52.328738900 -0500
+++ ciphers-jdk7-80-unlimited.txt       2019-01-17 16:05:37.783770600 -0500
@@ -1,64 +1,81 @@
+ TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
+ TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
+ TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
+ TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
+ TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
+ TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
+ TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
+ TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
+ TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
+ TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
+ TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
+ TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
+ TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
+ TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
  TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
+ TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
+ TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
+ TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
  SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
  SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
  SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
  TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
  TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
  TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
  TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
  TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
  TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
  TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
  TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
```

```java
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

/** Establish a SSL connection to a host and port, writes a byte and
 * prints the response. See
 * http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+to+SSL+services
 */
public class SSLPoke {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: "+SSLPoke.class.getName()+" <host> <port>");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
            if (true) {
                // https://www.baeldung.com/java-7-tls-v12
                SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
                sslContext.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());

                sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            } else {
                sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
                // This will cause an exception on connecting to a TLSv1.2-only server,
                // Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
                //         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:953)
                //         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
                //         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:709)
                //         at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
                //         at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:136)
                //         at SSLPoke.main(SSLPoke.java:66)
                // Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
                //         at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
                //         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
                //         ... 5 more
            }
            SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

            // https://gist.github.com/lanimall/cb808a11a058f7fb620a#file-gistfile1-java
            String[] protocols = sslSocket.getSupportedProtocols();

            System.out.println("Supported Protocols: " + protocols.length);
            for(int i = 0; i < protocols.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(" " + protocols[i]);
            }

            protocols = sslSocket.getEnabledProtocols();

            System.out.println("Enabled Protocols: " + protocols.length);
            for(int i = 0; i < protocols.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(" " + protocols[i]);
            }

            String[] ciphers = sslSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
            System.out.println("Enabled Ciphers: " + ciphers.length);
            for(int i = 0; i < ciphers.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(" " + ciphers[i]);
            }

            in = sslSocket.getInputStream();
            out = sslSocket.getOutputStream();

            // Write a test byte to get a reaction :)
            out.write(1);

            while (in.available() > 0) {
                System.out.print(in.read());
            }
            System.out.println("Successfully connected");

        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```